# How to set environment variables in desktop launcher (in UBUNTU)

Tags: nvidia, launcher, davinci-resolve

How can I correctly set the following environment variables in a `.desktop` launcher file?

To fix a problem with Davinci Resolve Studio it is necessary for my setup to set these two environment variables:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 
__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
```

Via the terminal I can launch Davinci Resolve Studio now with the following line successfully:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia /opt/resolve/bin/resolve
```

And I try to note these in the `.desktop` launcher like the following with no effect (see line 8, "Exec=..."). **What do I have to alter in this `.desktop` file to get this working?** I tried with and without the "env" command at the beginning so far.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=DaVinci Resolve
GenericName=DaVinci Resolve
Comment=Revolutionary new tools for editing, visual effects, color correction, and professional audio post-production, all in a single application!
Path=/opt/resolve/
Exec=env __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia /opt/resolve/bin/resolve %u
Terminal=false
MimeType=application/x-resolveproj;
Icon=/opt/resolve/graphics/DV_Resolve.png
StartupNotify=true
Name[en_US]=DaVinci Resolve
```

The parameters are exemplary here. I wonder what is missing here to get this working via a launcher.

Comment: The way you post it should work. Maybe you have another .desktop file that masks this one? Try placing it in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: Thanks @vanadium. After moving the file from the desktop to this directory it works!

Comment: Thanks @karel, I have seen that before, but this more general guide did not help me solve this problem.

Comment: Your comment "After moving the file from the desktop to this directory it works!" is the same as written in the accepted answer to [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/) so how could it not be a duplicate of that question?

Comment: I see what you mean, if there is another post explaining how to add these enviromental parameters to the Exec line of the .desktop file, I would not mind to mark this question as a duplicate. Because this was my question initially. Somebody looking for these parameters would not find the answer in this previous question, would they?

Comment: I will update my question and hightlight the solution. The Davinci Resolve installer put this .desktop file on the Desktop itself. So the problem is not obvious.

Comment: I found that selecting Performance Mode in the Nvidia settings/profiles allowed running my CUDA samples without the environment variables you use for Resolve.  The mode seems to switch which GPU is considered "primary".

Comment: Thanks @ubfan1! This makes sense in this case, too. I prefer the adaptive mode to save battery on my laptop in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Comment: @ArturMeinild, we had this question before. [This is](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435236/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-desktop-launcher-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment2501838_1435236) how I answered.

Comment: Actually when I add an evironmental variable, the icon does not work any more, does anyone knows how to fix this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461097/adding-an-enviromental-variable-in-desktop-icon-fails-the-desktop-icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [suggested by @vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435236/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-desktop-launcher-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment2501546_1435236) I just had to move this `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`.

See also this post for more information: [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/)