# Adding an enviromental variable in .desktop icon fails the desktop icon

Tags: bash, icons, launcher

I am editing the .desktop file for **microsoft edge**, originally the icon file works:

```
Comment[zh_CN]=访问互联网
Comment[zh_HK]=連線到網際網路
Comment[zh_TW]=連線到網際網路
Exec=/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=microsoft-edge
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

While after adding an environmental variable in the **Exec** the program won't start.

```
Comment[vi]=Truy cập Internet
Comment[zh_CN]=访问互联网
Comment[zh_HK]=連線到網際網路
Comment[zh_TW]=連線到網際網路
# Exec=/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable %U
Exec=env GTK_IM_MODULE=xim /usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable %U
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=microsoft-edge
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

Anyone knows how to correct this? (**GTK_IM_MODULE** is for ibus)

Comment: The first line of .desktop is "[Desktop Entry]",
you did not add it ?

Comment: The executable for microsoft edge is a bash-script, I export in that script directly to fix it.

Comment: I am editing the microsoft-edge.desktop, that header is originally there.

Comment: Oh maybe i know the reason,try  "gtk-launch  microsoft-edge" to start edge from command line , it will use microsoft-edge.desktop instead of  "/usr/bin/microsoft-edge"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executables for microsoft-edge and brave are bash scripts,I exported **GTK_IM_MODULE** and **XMODIFIERS** in the script /usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable and fixed the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright 2011 The Chromium Authors
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.
#ibus
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim #Fix for Chrome and Brave, when I start either of them from command lines
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
# Let the wrapped binary know that it has been run through the wrapper.
export CHROME_WRAPPER="`readlink -f "$0"`"
```